# first x characters of each element in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I have a large dataset (6M rows). For a given column - timestamp I want to take the first 11 characters of each element and construct a new column. So far I am doing it using the apply method but it takes a long time.

```
df_value_dl['time_sec'] = df_value_dl.apply(lambda x: str(x['timestamp'])[0:10], axis=1)
```

While looking for faster methods I came across [numpy arrays](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6)

What would be the correct syntax to do this using np arrays. Thanks

Comment: In `pandas` strings are python strings, in a column of `object` dtype.  `pandas` has some sort `str` method(s) that could make processing those strings faster.  `numpy` has a different string dtype, which could do this truncation, but conversion in/out of the pandas Series time consuming.  I suggest studying pandas docs for its string methods.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you haven't found an solution yet: This

```
df_value_dl['time_sec'] = df_value_dl['timestamp'].astype('string').str[:10]
```

should be faster than `apply`.